# Ubuntu Server Wirless Network Setup for Dell Inspiron 1300

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers

My house has two routers bridged together. WhiteBox (master) has WEP encryption, and BlackBox (slave) has WPA encryption.

I recently wiped and installed Ubuntu Server on my old Dell Inspiron 1300, and proceeded through installation via an ethernet connection.

In an attempt to get my built-in wireless to work, I have retrieved the `firmware-b43-installer` package, although I am unsure if there is some kind of shell script I have to run. `wlan0` has been enabled via `ifconfig`, and I am able to scan for both WhiteBox and BlackBox via `wlist`.

I've read around many forums trying to figure out what needs to be done, and I think that overall it is a driver problem. I have tried connecting to WhtieBox via `iwconfig` and BlackBox via `wpa-supplicant`, but have hit many bumps in the road. `wpa-supplicant` lists the available drivers as `n180211, wext, wired, none`.

I am a Linux novice. I can provide debug information.

Comment: Before providing debug info or installing drivers, you should identify the wireless card. To do that, run `lspci -nnk | grep 0280`, and add the output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your wireless device scans and sees both networks, then the driver/hardware combination is working.

Second, WEP is quite insecure. I suggest you set both routers to WPA2-AES.

Finally,  suggest you set up */etc/network/interfaces* something like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-ssid <your_router>
wpa-psk <your_wpa_key>
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

Be sure to select a static address outside the range used by the DHCP server in the router, switch or other access point. Of course, substitute your details here.

Get the system to read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0
```

Did you connect?

```
ping -c3 192.168.1.1
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```